# Tutorials to Testing using RSPEC on PADRINO framework on RUBY

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rspec2, padrino

I am `new to Ruby` and have been asked to use it in our new project. We have also been asked to use `Padrino (Sinatra)` as backend/framework. For testing we have been asked to use `Rspec`. I have been hunting for tutorials for long that would guide in `using Rspec for Ruby on Padrino`. What I get is mostly with reference to RoR. But, I am in need of Ruby on Padrino.

Please guide me for the same with any starters/guides/references/discussions, etc.

Please correct me, if I am wrong anywhere. May be I haven't searched with the right combination of words/phrases for my issue.

I am using `Ruby 1.9.3` and `Padrino v.0.10.6`.

Note : I have also referred the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201385/getting-started-with-rspec-looking-for-tutorials), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I never used Padrino, but it seems that it isn't much different from Sinatra.

I suggest reading Sinatra and RSpec resources. 
You can get started with this:

- [How to use rspec in a Sinatra Application](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-integrate-rspec-into-a-sinatra-app/)
- [Sinatra, RSpec and DataMapper: Configuring and using a database for tests](http://www.dinduks.com/sinatra-rspec-and-datamapper-configuring-and-using-a-database-for-tests)

And by reading specs that were written by other people on GitHub. [These are some of mine](https://github.com/Dinduks/furry-octo-ninja/tree/master/spec), but they are not the cleanest thing that exists.

---

**EDIT: a short tutorial**

Getting started with this framework is much quicker and easier than with Sinatra. :)

Install Padrino: `gem install padrino`

Create an application: `padrino g project myapp -d datamapper -t rspec`
The command speaks for itself. :)

Run the tests: `rspec --color`
No tests were found, obviously. Let's create one in `spec/hello/hello_spec.rb`:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../spec_helper.rb"

describe "get '/'" do
  it "should display hello world" do
    get '/'
    last_response.body.should == "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

Run the tests again.
They failed, because no route `get '/'` exists. Let's create it.

In `app/controllers/hello.rb`:

```
Myapp.controller do
  get '/' do
    "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

Run the test: it passes!

Check [Padrino's documentation](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides) for more information and cool features, such as the controllers generator and the admin interface.

Good luck!